# Tags for questions specific to decimal notation

Tags: discussion, tagging

Do we have a tag for questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761513/getting-multiple-of-11) which ask about properties specific to notating integers with base-ten digits?

If not, should we have one?

Of course for most such questions one can *imagine* generalizing to other bases, but often the OP will be most interested in base ten.

Answer (score 3):

We have [decimal-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decimal-expansion) tag. However, this is probably more suited for decimal expansions of real numbers, not for writing integer in base ten.

I think that the tag [number-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-systems) might be used. This tag is also suitable for expansions in other bases. The [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/number-systems/info) for (number-systems) says:

> Questions on the different ways to represent a number, how to convert between those different ways, and other such questions. The usual system employed by humans is the decimal (base-10) system, but other systems like binary and hexadecimal are also in frequent use.

This was briefly discussed in chat some time ago, see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4308452#4308452).
[This](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3169392#3169392) and [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3169341#3169341) discussion are also related, to some extent.

Comment: Wow, it was even me who started that chat discussion two years ago, and I had no recollection of it. What do you call a _lack of_ expected deja vu?

Comment: @HenningMakholm "A senior moment" [sorry]